# IBM Worklight Changes at Hybrid app on Native .js files disappear when i deploy the app, How could I mantain my changes?

Tags: android, deployment, ibm-mobilefirst

Changes at Hybrid app on Native .js files disappear when I deploy the app, the files on common are the originals when I create the project, I´m adding some functionalities on native .js files, first of all these files are read only, Where I must add these changes to appear again on my deployed project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the [training materials](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html). Specially: [Previewing your application on Android](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/02_03_Previewing_your_application_on_Android.pdf), slide #6.

The generated Android project receives its contents from the Worklight > Android folder.
If you then edit the contents of the generated Android project and re-build your Worklight project, your changes will be lost.

You must copy your changes back to the Worklight project. The Worklight project is your *Source*. The generated Android project is the *Destination*.

Comment: that was a weird way to do it, keeping a copy of my changes and replacing on android generated files, a good question would be, when I import a project with some functionalities added, How theses functionaties appear at my deployed project if the original .js file at common is empty?

Comment: I don't know what "functionalities" you have added, so I cannot answer your question. Please read the documentation...